# Local Notification To Load a View

Tags: objective-c, ios7, storyboard, xcode5, localnotification

I have an app that using local notifications, I want to have the app load a different page when a notification is recived. I also want it to load this new view when the slide to unlock over the notification is used.

My storyboards do not have a navigation controller is this possible to be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle local notifications in the following ways:

Add in following method located in AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

This code:

```
// Handle launching from a notification
UILocalNotification *locationNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (locationNotification) {
    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    // redirect to UIViewController
    UIStoryboard * storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController * notificationViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IdentifierOfViewController"];
    self.window.rootViewController = notificationViewController; // set the new UIViewController
}
```

This allows you to handle LOCAL notifications as soon as the app is launched, either by acting on a 'slide to view' dialog or just by opening the app.
You can then change the rootViewController in the application if there is a notification

> My storyboards do not have a navigation controller is this possible to
>   be done?

Yes, this wouldn't be a problem as long you use modal navigation.

**EDIT**

If you want to handle the notifications if the app is currently opened by the user you can catch the notification, by placing the following method in the AppDelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```